# Proxy+vpn settings

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

I have private proxies, i.e., I configure them through the Windows settings, and after that I want to connect to the VPN.

Will the connection to the VPN be carried out from my native IP address or from the proxy IP address? In the settings, the inscription confuses me (highlighted in red in the picture), so I'm not sure which IP address will connect to the VPN.

[image: proxy settings]